# C# Pointers to other application's memory

Tags: c#, .net, unsafe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access structure in other program's memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986047/how-to-access-structure-in-other-programs-memory)

Hello.
I want to access another application memory.
I'm writing game hack (Don't worry, it's only for single-player mode).
I have found pointer to player structure in game's memory.

I don't want to use pInvoked ReadProcessMemory because I want to be able to read individual structure's field. I know address in game's memory where is array of player structs.

Using pInvoked ReadProcessMemory is not very practical in this case.

How can I use C#'s unsafe pointers to map other processes memory as struct?
Or if it's not possibe to use direct pointers, what would be the way of using readPrcessMemory?

I want in the end to be able to so sth like that.

player is some kind of class representing struct in memory.
Players is some kind Collection of players.

```
foreach(player guy in Players)
{ 
    DrawESP(guy.X, guy.Y, guy.Z);
}
```

Comment: You asked this question already (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986047/how-to-access-structure-in-other-programs-memory). We already answered it (at some length). Why are you asking again? Just because you don't like the answer you already got doesn't mean it isn't correct. You have to use ReadProcessMemory. Please accept one of the answers from the earlier question and please stop re-posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot simply recompile from memory like that.

Create the object's structure in your own application (class/struct/etc) and use ReadProcessMemory to read in the appropriate bytes, then intepret those bytes in such a way as to fill your structure.

If you're not familiar with using pointers in such a manner, I would politely suggest writing trainers is not for you and you need to do some reading first.

I'd suggest learning to write trainers in C++, it's significantly easier to think in terms of 'unsafe' code that way.

Comment: You didn't read my post. I know very well how to use ReadProcessMemory. I have made many trainers for many games(Mw2, Black Ops, Battlefield BC2) But Reading 18 structs value by value makes my ESP hack very slow. That's why I want to do it by pointers.

Comment: Yes I did. You're asking for the impossible, so I'm trying to politely redirect you to the actual solution. You cannot 'magically' map memory into C# objects, it requires you to interpret it from bytes (ie. work) [For posterity, this post dealt with 'You didn't read my post', not later edits]

Comment: @Hooch you can calculate offset for particular field and read it by ReadProcessMemory.

Comment: "But Reading 18 structs value by value makes my ESP hack very slow. That's why I want to do it by pointers."

Do you understand what a pointer is? A pointer is just a location in memory. It doesn't 'do' anything, nor make anything faster.

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for that. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: If you want to access individual elements on the memory without copying the entire structures into your application's memory, you'll have to write a wrapper than looks at the offsets and pulls out the appropriate offsets. That wrapper being mentioned in my initial post.

Comment: @Rushyo I ant to access memory directly. I don't want to use function like ReadProcessMemory if it's possible.

Comment: Microsoft definition of ReadProcessMemory:

"Reads data from an area of memory" If you want to read memory from another process, you're going to have to call some low-level function to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- ReadProcessMemory
- Load a DLL into the remote process, that DLL can then access memory directly using unsafe pointers.

Comment: OK. That's not bad. I mean second option. Can i inject C# dll into not managed process? If it's possible, how can I communicate with that dll?

Comment: @Hooch: Yes, you can inject managed DLLs.  It used to be recommended against, back when only one version of .NET could be used per process, but with .NET 4 multiple versions can run side-by-side so it shouldn't be an issue.  For communication to your DLL you have all the usual IPC suspects: sockets, shared memory, pipes, kernel events, mailslots, files, etc.

Comment: Can you give me link to some kind of tutorial where I can learn how to do that?

Comment: @Hooch: [SO has this really neat feature](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+DLL+injection) [that can help you with that](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+inject+DLL)